# object # server has no method 'use'

Tags: node.js, express

could you help me to solve the following problem :)
i using node version 0.10.33,npm version 1.4.28 and express version 1.4.28

when i run the following js code

```
var express = require("express"),
         exp = express(),
         http= require('http'); 
    var app = http.createServer(exp),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
//  io = require('socket.io')(app);



var redis = require("redis"),
    rclient = redis.createClient();

app.listen(8080);
//app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
app.configure(function() {
app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
})
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var board_sockets = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var board_id = socket.handshake.query.board_id;
    if(!board_sockets[board_id]) board_sockets[board_id] = [];
    // TODO: Do something if the board_id is undefined
    board_sockets[board_id].push(socket);
    var redis_key = "board_" + board_id;
    rclient.lrange(redis_key, 0, -1, function(err, res) {
        socket.emit('board_state', res);
    });

    socket.on('update', function (data) {
        for(idx in board_sockets[board_id]) {
            var s = board_sockets[board_id][idx];
            if(s != socket) {
                s.emit('update', data);
                data.timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
                rclient.lpush(redis_key, JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

i got this error 
object # server has no method 'configure'

Comment: `express version 1.4.28`? Isn't it a typo?

Comment: no , when i write this command

Comment: npm express -v   the returened value 1.4.28

Comment: It's a version of `npm` itself. Try `npm ls express` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `app` is an instance of [`http.Server` class](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) which indeed has neither `.configure` nor `.use` in its prototype.

Probably, you intended to write `exp.use(...)` instead of `app.use(...)`.

By the way, `app.configure` has been deprecated since express 3.13.0 and completely removed since express 4.0.0.